# How do I close the "Welcome to Chrome" window when using protractor + appium to test mobile devices

Tags: android, protractor, appium

I've been searching all day. I found a couple of related problems but none of the solutions fixed my issue.

Every time I run my tests on an Android emulator running Chrome, using protractor and Appium the "Welcome to Chrome" message pops up. I've tried a few different version of chrome and a bunch of adb shell commands. I've tried clicking it using a different methods, I've tried opening a new window.. etc etc. I can't seem to figure out a consistent way to close the damn message besides just manually clicking it which is unacceptable.

Does anyone know how to turn it off for good?